# How to Activate AdBlocker in Chrome using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, adblock

I would like to activate Adblocker for Chrome with Selenium WebDriver Java.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 6):

You can either use the crx file of the extension or point to a directory it's installed in. Assuming you have it installed, you'll need to add `ChromeOptions` to your `new ChromeDriver`:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("load-extension=/path/to/extension");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

See [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions) for more details and walkthrough.

EDIT: to see your extensions path, navigate to `chrome://version` and look at 'Profile Path'. In that folder look for 'Extensions' folder. The extension ID for AdBlock Plus is `cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb`. So the path/to/extension should be something like (Windows):

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<profile>\Extensions\cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb
```

Comment: unable to find the path of plug in(CRX), where it is actually loacted?

Comment: There are many folders in 'Extensions' folder. How can I identify the extension ID for AdBlock Plus?

Comment: In my case I didn't find the ID on Chrome (version 69.0.3497.100) so I had to use the extension version and check on each folder (not the best way but can works for anyone)

Comment: Thanks, I needed a crx file too, I zipped the extension (.crx is a simple zip fle) and it worked right away. https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/ works too.